# Creating group style file

Tags: geoserver, sld, geoserver-css-module, ysld

Suppose i want to group 2 or more style of different layers into one SLD file. How can i do it ?

A pointer towards the working example or document will do.

Or any alternative styling example such as CSS will do it it fits in above requirements.

Comment: This SLD example file has numerous named layers - is this what you need?  [http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/tasmania/sld-tasmania.xml](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/tasmania/sld-tasmania.xml)

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do, maybe that will help us understand better

Answer (score 1):

The SLD can contain multiple < NamedLayer > allowing you to have multiple styles for multiple layers in a single SLD. In Geoserver you can apply a "Style Group" from within the "Layer Groups" menu item. You need to put all of your layers into a Layer Group first. The Layer Group can then access the Style Group (which is an SLD with more than one < NamedLayer >). Hope that helps!